# How can I import types from a .d.ts file in a .js file with the same name

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, jsdoc

I’m writing JavaScript code and want type safety with TypeSript via [JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html).

Because it’s just nicer to write types in TypeScript I wanted to put the type definitions in a `.d.ts` file right next to my `.js` file:

```js
// person.d.ts
export type Person = {
  name: string;
}
```

```js
// person.js

/** @type {import("./person").Person} */
let person;

person = {
  name2: "sdf", // <-- this should error, but does not
};
```

The issue is, that this does seem to break the TypeScript checker.

If I rename `person.d.ts` to `foo.d.ts` and import `./foo` instead, it works.

What is strange, is that TypeScript seems to see and understand the type, it just doesn’t properly interpret it:

[image: Screenshot of VSCode, showing that the type Person is imported properly]

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: here is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.js", "./**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I added the config to the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is actually a very obscure `tsc` "feature".

Consider the following `tsconfig`:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "listFiles": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

```bash
$ tree -L 2
.
├── node_modules
│   ├── reverse-line-reader
│   └── typescript
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── person.d.ts
│   └── person.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Now run `tsc`:

```
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.importscripts.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.scripthost.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.decorators.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.decorators.legacy.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/src/person.d.ts
```

You can see only `person.d.ts` is picked up by the compiler, even though `person.js` clearly exists. There are also no reported errors.

Now remove the `include` section from `tsconfig.json`:

```
$ tsc
src/person.js:7:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ name2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'name2' does not exist in type 'Person'. Did you mean to write 'name'?

7     name2: "sdf", // <-- this should error, but does not
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~

/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.importscripts.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.scripthost.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.decorators.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.decorators.legacy.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/src/person.d.ts
/home/user/source/module/src/person.js

Found 1 error in src/person.js:7
```

Now *magically* both `person.js` and `person.d.ts` are picked up by the compiler. Why?

It seems that when using `include`, `tsc` will for some reason exclude files it thinks may have been emitted (auto-generated) by `tsc` in a previous run. For example, if you had a `person.ts` file and ran `tsc`, it would produce a file named `person.js` and `person.d.ts` (with `declaration` set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`).

The only explanation I have ever seen is [this document which is technically deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tutorials/tsconfig.json.md#details):

> Please note that the compiler does not include files that can be possible outputs; e.g. if the input includes index.ts, then index.d.ts and index.js are excluded. In general, having files that differ only in extension next to each other is not recommended.

However, it appears to still be true to this day.

In short, one solution is to simply remove the `include` section entirely. It is not needed in this case, and usually not unless you have a fairly complex repository.

Alternatively, as the documentation suggests, you can move your types into a different folder entirely, or all into a monolithic file.